# how to make a macro in python 2.7.10 mac?

Tags: python, macos

Yeah the title is pretty self explanatory. I'm trying find a way to make python simulate a key press, and all I can find is windows only, and since my computer broke so I'm using my parents computer, I can't download anything, so it won't be helpful if it requires downloading a module.

Comment: it requires downloading module - like PyAutoGUI - read [Chapter 18 – Controlling the Keyboard and Mouse with GUI Automation](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/). So if you can't download then we can close this question.

Comment: See if [these scripts](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63897/can-a-mac-be-programmed-to-simulate-pressing-a-key-at-a-certain-rate-via-softwar) work for you. If so, they can be adapted to Python, or called via Python, using the built-in `subprocess` module.